# Will an app that is useful for a small organisation only be approved in Apple's AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to know, if an iPhone app is targeted on a specific organisation? e.g. a tool dedicated for a specific neighbourhood school, will this application be accepted by Apple?

I have read through the guideline (http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

The closest I can find is this "Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the app, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected"

I need to know a more specific and confirm answer? yes? no?

Comment: It depends.  I think what they are talking about In the documentation are the dinks who decide to put an app up that only 5 people have functional access to (logins and such).  How big are you talking?  Would it have at least minimal appeal to consumers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you're going to get a definitive answer here on SO.  The bottom line is that Apple may accept or reject anything at their sole discretion.

That said, I developed an app for a client targeting a very niche market (it was basically a configuration tool for a hardware device they sell), and it was approved no questions asked.

Comment: Thanks. Its great to know that Apple does allow very niche app!

Answer (score 0):

You can register for enterprise license http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ . For this your app need-not go through AppStore. Read "Terms And Conditions" to know if it suits you.

Comment: Hi sach, thanks for your input...I am aware of the enterprise license. It is expensive for small organisation, imagine I have distribute 5 apps to 5 small organisation, By Law I should apply 5 enterprise licenses... which is way too much than submitting them to app store...